# How to create an array populated with DateTime elements

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to create a method to create an array full of `DateTime` objects. The problem is that when I try to print the array on the console, it just tells me `System.DateTime[]`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
using System;

namespace exercise_5
{
    class Program
    {
        public static DateTime[] TimeSeries(int a, string b, int c)
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(b, "dd-mm-yyyy", null);
            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(c);
            DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[a];
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                dates[0] = date;
                dates[i] = date + ts;

            }
            return dates;
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            int a = 20;
            string b = "01-04-2020";
            int c = 20;
            Console.WriteLine(TimeSeries(a, b, c));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You either need to iterate over the results from `TimeSeries` and print out each one or use `string.Join` to create a string representation of them.

Answer (score 3):

To get the desired output replace this line:

```
Console.WriteLine(TimeSeries(a, b, c));
```

with

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join('\n', TimeSeries(a,b,c).Select(a=>a.ToString()));
```

If you want to loop over the result, you have to use `foreach` or other tools, here is how:

```
foreach(var d in TimeSeries(a,b,c))
     Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
```

Comment: Note you don't need the `.Select(a=>a.ToString())` as `string.Join` a generic overload that takes a `IEnumerable<T>` and will call `ToString` for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public static void Main()
{
    int a = 20;
    string b = "01-04-2020";
    int c = 20;
    var dates = TimeSeries(a, b, c)
    foreach(var date in dates)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(date.ToString());
    }
}
```

Also you may want to try something like this:

```
dates.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.ToString()));
```

Comment: I die a little inside every time I see someone use `ToList().ForEach`

Comment: You're iterating the collection to create a List just to turn around and iterate the list and throw it away.

Comment: @Frak12 `ForEach()` encourages side effects in an extension method which is poor design.  Also, you are unnecessarily creating a list just to use that extension method.  Its just not a clean way of doing things at all

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i will pay more attention about this